# How to execute a insert query multiple times into a table with mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

For testing the TTFB for single pages loaded by a CMS I wan't to add new pages into my database without doing it one for one inside a CMS. For example I wan't to execute the query as below a 100 times inside a table, but how can I do this in mySql/phpmyadmin?

**This query must be execute for 100 times**

```
INSERT INTO `bolt_pages` (`id`, `slug`, `datecreated`, `datechanged`, `datepublish`, `datedepublish`, `username`, `ownerid`, `status`, `templatefields`, `title`, `image`, `teaser`, `body`, `template`) VALUES (NULL, 'hello-world', '2017-05-15 12:01:35', '2017-05-15 13:22:43', '2017-05-15 12:01:13', NULL, '', '1', 'published', '[]', 'Hello world', NULL, '<p>teaser</p>\r\n', '<p>Hello world</p>\r\n', '');
```

Comment: Create a stored procedure. You can even have a parameter for the number of inserts to execute,

Comment: Why don't you use `Repeat`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926264/how-can-i-run-a-query-multiple-times-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a procedure should be...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE simple_loop ( )
BEGIN
  DECLARE counter BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

  my_loop: LOOP
    SET counter=counter+1;

    IF counter=100 THEN
      LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;

    #SELECT counter; #uncomment if you'd like to print the counter

    INSERT INTO `bolt_pages` (`id`, `slug`, `datecreated`, `datechanged`, `datepublish`, `datedepublish`, `username`, `ownerid`, `status`, `templatefields`, `title`, `image`, `teaser`, `body`, `template`) VALUES (NULL, 'hello-world', '2017-05-15 12:01:35', '2017-05-15 13:22:43', '2017-05-15 12:01:13', NULL, '', '1', 'published', '[]', 'Hello world', NULL, '<p>teaser</p>\r\n', '<p>Hello world</p>\r\n', '');

  END LOOP my_loop;
END$$
DELIMITER
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Repeat` , or you can create a `procedure` as well:

```
SET @K = 0;
    lab1: REPEAT
    INSERT INTO `bolt_pages` (`id`, `slug`, `datecreated`, `datechanged`, `datepublish`, `datedepublish`, `username`, `ownerid`, `status`, `templatefields`, `title`, `image`, `teaser`, `body`, `template`) VALUES (NULL, 'hello-world', '2017-05-15 12:01:35', '2017-05-15 13:22:43', '2017-05-15 12:01:13', NULL, '', '1', 'published', '[]', 'Hello world', NULL, '<p>teaser</p>\r\n', '<p>Hello world</p>\r\n', '');
    Set @k = @k +1;
    UNTIL @K > 100 END REPEAT lab1;
```

Comment: When I wan't to execute this query, it say's that `Repeat` is a not recognized command.

Comment: Getting SQL Error (1064) .. syntax to use near 'REPEAT Set @k = @k +1' at line 1. Mysql Server version is 5.7.19-log.